# Installations on Separate Disks

Tags: system-installation, windows, 13.04

I'm having trouble installing ubuntu 13.04 on my windows 8 machine. The slot one disk is a 360gb SSD with W8, but the disk I want to install Ubuntu on is a 120gb SSD. I keep trying to install the OS, but it tells me there's no root system on the 120gb SSD that I want to use. I was wondering if anyone could help because I cannot find what I think is a relevant article.

Comment: Could you write out the exact steps you are taking. For example, are you choosing the **Something Else** option? If so, how are you partitioning the 120GB SSD?

Comment: See http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2011/05/04/manual-disk-partitioning-guide-for-ubuntu-11-04/ I wouldn't bother with `/boot` partition. Make 3 parititions. Make sure the first is `/` and the second is `/home` both in **ext4  Journaling File System**. The last is `Swap Area` with no mount point.

Answer (score 0):

With 2 drives it is important to partition second drive as gpt partitioned not the usual default MBR(msdos). I might also make an efi partition on that drive even though system will only boot thru one efi partition. Then you could boot Ubuntu SSD without Windows drive, if you also install grub2's boot loader to both efi partitions.

Then you should be able to install in UEFI mode following the UEFI type installs.

I have only BIOS but use gpt and use gparted to partition drives.
I used gparted and selected gpt under device, advanced & select gpt over msdos(MBR) default partitioning....